# Print a list of checked form options in TWIG

Tags: theming, 8

I need to print out a list of checked form options in a TWIG template in Drupal 8.

I'm using Better Exposed Filters, and editing the `views-exposed-form.html.twig` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the form options, returning the # value of each item:

`{% for choice in form.filter['#value'] %}`

Then Print out the title value of each one of those options:

`{{ form.filter[choice]['#title'] }}`

**All together it looks like this:**

```
{% for choice in form.filter['#value'] %} {# Find each checked option #}
  {{ form.filter[choice]['#title'] }} {# Print the Title #}
{% endfor %}
```